# How can I get the type of a file or folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying some directories with all of their content and sub-directories in a listbox. Now I want to get the item type, size, modified time of each item in another listbox. I am successful in displaying the size and modified time but how can I display the type e.g whether it's a File Folder / Text File / Pdf file or Image? This is in the Windows Explorer detail view in which we can see the types, size and modification time of a file. How can I do this?

Here is my code for size and last modified time:

```
private void ShowFilesIn(string dir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    lstFiles.Items.Clear();
    list_size.Items.Clear();
    list_modified.Items.Clear();
    list_type.Items.Clear();
    string downloadlink;        

    foreach (FileInfo fileItem in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        downloadlink = fileItem.Directory + "/" + fileItem.Name ;
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = fileItem.Name;
        li.Value = downloadlink;
        lstFiles.Items.Add(li);
        list_size.Items.Add(fileItem.Length.ToString());
        list_type.Items.Add(Path.GetExtension(fileItem.Name));
        list_modified.Items.Add(fileItem.LastWriteTime.ToString());
     }
}
```

The GetExtension() method is displaying the extension but I want the file type as shown in Windows Explorer, for example: File Folder, JPEG Image, Text file etc.

Comment: What you mean under `type of a folder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the information using [SHFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759792(v=vs.85).aspx)

This is how you can get the FileType Info or a folder in c#.

```
string filePath = .... // your File Path
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(filePath);

//detect whether its a directory or file
if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory)
{
   SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
   IntPtr intptr = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(fullpath, 0, ref shinfo,    (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), Win32.SHGFI_TYPENAME);
   var typeName = Convert.ToString(shinfo.szTypeName.Trim());
}
else 
{
  // it is Folder
}


struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public int dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
}

 [Flags]
 enum FileInfoFlags : int
 {
     SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100,     // get icon
     SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200,     // get display name
     SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400,     // get type name
     SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800,     // get attributes
     SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000,     // get icon location
     SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000,     // return exe type
     SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000,     // get system icon index
     SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000,     // put a link overlay on icon
     SHGFI_SELECTED = 0x000010000,     // show icon in selected state
     SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED = 0x000020000,     // get only specified attribtes
     SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000,     // get large icon
     SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001,     // get small icon
     SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002,     // get open icon
     SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004,     // get shell size icon
     SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008,     // pszPath is a pidl
     SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010,     // use passed dwFileAttribute
     SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS = 0x000000020,     // apply the appropriate overlays
     SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX = 0x000000040,     // Get the index of the overlay in 
     // the upper 8 bits of the iIcon
 }

 public class Win32
 {
    public const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x00000200;
    public const uint SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x400;
    public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
    public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0; // 'Large icon
    public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1; // 'Small icon

   [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint
        dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);
}
```

Comment: what is the namespace for SHFILEINFO ?

Comment: It's a P/Invoke call, so expect your code to be thoroughly bound to Windows.

Comment: @AlinaAnjum, Make a new File and place struct  SHFILEINFO, enum FileInfoFlags and class Win32 in that file. Now you can call this Win32.SHGetFileInfo(....) from anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GetMimeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) to get the [MimeType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of each file from it's path.

Comment: can you please elaborate the syntax how can i use this method?

Comment: this is available for .net 4.5 and i am working on 2.0 :(